# How to consolidate nested list elements

Tags: python, algorithm

I've written a Python script that parses a lot of data and cleans it up as per the example below:

```
input_list = [[a,b,c,0.5], [a,b,d,1], [a,b,e,1], [a,b,c,0.3], [a,b,c,0.2], [a,b,f,0.6], [a,b,f,0.4], [a,b,g,1]]

output_list = [[a,b,c,1], [a,b,d,1], [a,b,e,1], [a,b,f,1], [a,b,g,1]]
```

So basically, if the first 3 elements of each list are identical, then only one list is preserved and the values (4th element) are added up.

I've used nested 'for' loops and a lot of 'if' statements but I'm wondering if there's a nicer way to do this in Python (v2 preferably).

I'm not asking for code here, just some suggestions so I can learn and improve my code.

Cheers.

Comment: It would be great if you can include your original code so we can see what you did :)

Comment: Show your code, then we cloud help you to improve and get it more nested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
input_list = [['a','b','c',0.5], ['a','b','d',1], ['a','b','e',1], ['a','b','c',0.3], ['a','b','c',0.2], ['a','b','f',0.6], ['a','b','f',0.4], ['a','b','g',1]]
output_list = []

d = {}
for i in input_list:
    key = (i[0], i[1], i[2])
    d[key] = i[3] + (d[key] if key in d else float(0))

for k, v in d.iteritems():
    output_list.append([
        k[0], k[1], k[2], v
    ])

# print output_list
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I'd never thought about about using dictionaries for this so this is a great learning moment! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know how many elements will match and you need to keep track of what you've found for specific keys so far, using a dict as an intermediary data type makes sense.

Here's a working solution:

```
totals = {}
for a, b, c, x in input_list:
    key = (a, b, c)
    if key in totals:
        totals[key] += x
    else:
        totals[key] = x
result = [[k[0], k[1], k[2], v] for k, v in totals.items()]
```

What this does:

- loop over the input_list
- combine the first three values of every element into a key
- check if the key is in a dictionary
- if it is, add the fourth value to it, otherwise add the fourth value as a new value
- at the end, turn the dictionary into a list matching the original structure

In Python 3, the last line would be better as:

```
result = [[*k, v] for k, v in totals.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good usecase of [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), and it works for both `python2` and `python3`.

We essentially group all elements together with the same first 3 elements, sum up the 4th elements of all such groups, and create the result list

```
from itertools import groupby
input_list = [['a','b','c',0.5], ['a','b','d',1], ['a','b','e',1], ['a','b','c',0.3], ['a','b','c',0.2], ['a','b','f',0.6], ['a','b','f',0.4], ['a','b','g',1]]

#Sort the input list based on first three elements
input_list = sorted(input_list, key=lambda x:x[:3])
res = []

#Group the input list based on first three elements
for model, group in groupby(input_list, key=lambda x:x[:3]):

    #Sum up the 4th element for the same first 3 elements and cast to int
    fourth_val = int(sum([item[3] for item in group]))

    #Create the list by adding the common first 3 elements with the sum
    res.append(model+[fourth_val])

print(res)
```

The output will be

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 1], ['a', 'b', 'd', 1], 
['a', 'b', 'e', 1], ['a', 'b', 'f', 1], 
['a', 'b', 'g', 1]]
```

Another approach is to use a dictionary, with the key being the first 3 elements of the list, and summing up values of the 4th element

```
input_list = [['a','b','c',0.5], ['a','b','d',1], ['a','b','e',1], ['a','b','c',0.3], ['a','b','c',0.2], ['a','b','f',0.6], ['a','b','f',0.4], ['a','b','g',1]]

dct = {}

#Iterate through input list
for x,y,z, a in input_list:
    #Take the first 3 elements as the key
    k = x,y,z

    #Add up 4th value for common first 3 elements
    dct.setdefault(k,0)
    dct[k]= a+dct[k]

#Convert dictionary back to list
res = [ [x,y,z,int(v)] for (x,y,z), v in dct.items()]

print(res)
```

Comment: Great, Glad to help, Please upvote or accept if the answer helped you @lolo :)

Comment: Thanks @lolo  for the upvote, I have also included a shorter way to use dictionary based approach as an update to my answer, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

I think I got an answer for you:

```
input_list = [["a", "b", "c", 0.5], ["a", "b", "d", 1], ["a", "b", "e", 1],
              ["a", "b", "c", 0.3], ["a", "b", "c", 0.2], ["a", "b", "f", 0.6],
              ["a", "b", "f", 0.4], ["a", "b", "g", 1]]

output_list = []
for i in range(len(input_list)):
    letters = [x[0:3] for x in output_list]

    if input_list[i][0:3] in letters:
        used = letters.index(input_list[i][0:3])
        output_list[used][3] += input_list[i][3]
    else:
        output_list.append(input_list[i])

print(output_list)
```

output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 1.0], ['a', 'b', 'd', 1], ['a', 'b', 'e', 1], ['a', 'b', 'f', 1.0], ['a', 'b', 'g', 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
def foo(input_list):
    seen = {}
    for x1, x2, x3, x4 in input_list:
        seen[(x1, x2, x3)] = seen.setdefault((x1, x2, x3), 0) + x4
    return [[x1, x2, x3, x4] for (x1, x2, x3), x4 in seen.items()]
```

You can unpack values like this `*x, y = 1,2,3,4` in modern python but I don't think legacy python has that feature.